# PowerShell Positional Parameters and ParameterSets

Tags: powershell

I've been working on a PowerShell cmdlet to enrol a user in a course. It should take a user parameter and a course parameter, but either parameter can come in the form of an object (e.g. an instance of "User") or an integer ID.

I've created a Gist to show my reproduction here:

[PowerShell Parameter Madness](https://gist.github.com/mabster/27019f04bacd48c76e16754a1b702a2e)

Named parameters all work fine, but for the life of me I can't get positional parameters to work reliably. These reproduction cases at the bottom of my example script:

```
New-Enrolment $user.Id $course.Id
New-Enrolment $user $course.Id
New-Enrolment $user.Id $course 
New-Enrolment $user $course
$user | New-Enrolment $course.Id
$user | New-Enrolment $course
$course | New-Enrolment $user 
$course | New-Enrolment $user.id
```

... should all work as far as I can see from my ParameterSetName combinations, but some of them fail (at least in PowerShell 5.1).

Any PowerShell wonks out there that want to have a crack at this and tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: PowerShell attempts to bind positional parameters and then infer the appropriate parameter set _before_ it can receive the first input item via the pipeline! You'll have to choose between `UserId` or `CourseId` as the first positional `[int]`

Comment: Gotcha. So if I choose UserId as the first positional, I'll always have to do -Course or -CourseId when passing in $User via the pipeline.